# Hyperion RDBMS Table

Tags: rdbms, hyperion, essbase

As we know details of every job are stored in rdbms in table Hsp_Job_Status. But unfortunately this table gets truncated each time we re-start services. As per business requirement we needed to keep a record of BR's launched by user and it's details. So we had developed a work around and created a trigger on the table such that it inserted each new row/update in a backup table. This was working fine uptill now.

Recently after re-start the the values of old Job_id (i.e primary key), are not appearing in order. It started series form a previous number. It was going in series of 106XX but after re-start the numbering started from 100XX. As Hsp_job_status was truncated during restart, there was no issue of duplicate primary key in that table. But it created duplicate values in backup table. And  this has created issues with backup table and procedure that we use.
Usually the series is continuous one even after table truncate. So may be some thing has gone wrong during restart. Can you please suggest me as to what should i check and do to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: the simple solution is to insert an instance prefix to the Job_Id, and on service startup increment the active instance.  The instance table can then include details from startup/shutdown events to help drive SLA metrics.  Unfortunately, I don't know how you would go about implementing such a scheme, since it's been many years since I've spoken any SQL dialects.